# сдвиг массива на к позиций

Tags: javascript

пытаюсь  сдвинуть элементы  массива вправо на к позиций,элементы сдвигаются вродебы правильно но среди них один undefined следовательно я затираю один элемент,как это исправить?

```
var a=[1,2,3,45,8,9,7,10]
var k=3;//шаг
var n=a.length;var temp=[];
for(i=0;i<=k;i++){temp[i]=a[n-k+i];}  
for(i=n-1;i>=k;i--){a[i]=a[i-k];}  
for(i=0;i<=k;i++){a[i]=temp[i];}  
console.log(a)
//должно быть [9, 7, 10, 1, 2, 3, 45, 8]
```

Comment: `i < k;` a нe `i <= k;`

Comment: @abascakov  Покажите на этом примере, какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [9, 7, 10, 1, 2, 3, 45, 8]

Answer (score 5):

Циклический сдвиг массива лучше делать так:

```
var a=[1,2,3,45,8,9,7,10]
var k=3;//шаг
for(i=0;i<k;i++) a.unshift(a.pop());
console.log(a);
```

`pop()` - Удаляет элемент с конца массива и возвращает его. `unshift()` добавляет переданный элемент в начало массива

Или проще:

```
a=a.splice(-k).concat(a);
```

Comment: `a.length-k,k` можно заменить на `-k`

Comment: @Grundy Круто. поправил :)

Comment: @abascakov Я бы на вашем месте выбрал этот ответ (который однострочник)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать это в одну строчку

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 45, 8, 9, 7, 10];
        var k = 3;

        a = a.concat(a.splice(0, a.length - k));
        alert(a);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

всё нашел свою ошибку,если есть ответы более элегантные то прошу написать их

```
var a=[1,2,3,45,8,9,7,10]
var k=3; 
var n=a.length;var temp=[];
for(i=0;i<k;i++){temp[i]=a[n-k+i];}  
for(i=n-1;i>=k;i--){a[i]=a[i-k];}  
for(i=0;i<k;i++){a[i]=temp[i];}  
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант с функцией [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 45, 8, 9, 7, 10]
var k = 3; //шаг
document.body.innerHTML = 'a = '+ JSON.stringify(a) + '<br/>k = '+k+'<br/>';

a = a.map(function(el, index, arr) {
  return index < k ? arr[arr.length + index - k] : arr[index - k]
});

document.body.innerHTML += 'new a = '+ JSON.stringify(a);
```